# How do you pass data from Html to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, variables

I have a table of **Products**. I get these products from my controller action, I run a `foreach` loop and name each **Product** `product`. Each **Product** has an **Id**. I then create a row for that **Product** with a **Delete** button by the last cell.

I can call with **ajax** (in **JavaScript**) an **Api** to delete a **Product** from my database, the syntax of that **Https request** is like this: `https://mywebsite.com/api/products/1` (**1** is the **Id** and changes based on which product I choose to delete).

So the problem is that I call this **Api** after the user hits **Yes** on the confirmation dialog, so I need to do everything in the callback function of the dialog, and that is in the **JavaScript**, and I need to call the **Https** with the **Id** by the end, so how do I get the Id?

Comment: Please include any relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use data attributes, for example

```js
var article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

```html
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes